# DAX - Multiple Sub Total, check subtotal index or something similar

Tags: powerpivot, dax

[image]

Please see attached screen. Here I would like to calculate two sub totals for Test_4 measure for half year/semester level. If I use

```
Test_4 := IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(PeriodMonth[MonthNumber]))=1,[Total Sale],[Total Purchase])
```

I am getting the same value for both subtotals.

Can anyone please suggest how can I modify the DAX to return the values as I have highlighted in the screen attached.

**Update:**

Not sure why I am finding it hard to get it. I am simply trying to calculate two sub totals by detecting the sub total. Please see another screen attached below: 
[image]

Here Test_4 has been calculated as:

```
Test_4 := IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(PeriodMonth[MonthNumber]))=1,1,COUNTROWS(VALUES(PeriodMonth[MonthNumber])))
```

which return 6 for both sub totals. If I know at which sub total I am at I can calculate the sub total differently. So my question is how I can determine the sub total or it is not possible with the approach I am using.

I hope I am clear. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but try using the HasOneValue() function to determine if you are looking at a month, semester or year.

Comment: @mmarie, suppose you would like to display semester total and semester % calculations from PP model, how would you do that?

Comment: and your Month is in columns.